# THC Hydra false positives on Foscam login

Tags: http, brute-force, hydra

I bought a Foscam C1 Lite this week and I want to try to brute force the login page with THC hydra.

But currently I am getting false positives with the following command:

```
hydra -s 88 -l user -P passlist.txt 10.0.0.125 http-get-form "index.php:username=^USER^&password=^PASS^&Login=Login:Username / password do not match"
```

I looked at the code of the website and I didn't see an form element, so how can I succeed with my testing? Does anybody has any tips for me?

This is an example o a Foscam authentication page: `http://85.148.28.169:88/` because my Foscam is only accessable within my WLAN.